# Не могу обновить centos через yum update

Tags: linux, centos, centos7

Есть небольшая KVM VPS  (256MB RAM) с установленной на ней centos 7.0.1406
Захотел обновиться до последней версии, вбил в putty команду `yum update` но во время установки сервер неожиданно сбросил соединение. На VPS данных небыло, поэтому переинсталлил и попробовал опять - опять сбросил на том же месте. Опять переинсталлил - снова на том же месте сбросил. Решил попробовать обновить лишь ядро `yum update kernel` но и тут не получается - VPS сбрасывает соединение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чём может быть причина и как решить проблему?

Comment: очевидно же: обратиться в соответствующую техподдержку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего не хватает оперативной памяти - для этой операции нужно минимум 512 MB RAM